# How to create two partitions with exactly the same size?

Tags: gparted, disk, partitioning

I created two partitions using the following commands.

```
parted /dev/sda --script -- mkpart primary 1 50001
parted /dev/sda --script -- mkpart primary 1948001 1998001
```

Each partition should have 50001 MB. However, when I use "partclone" trying to copy from the first partition to the second, it complains that these two partitions are not the same size. The second one is 50000 MB.

When I do "fdisk -l", below is the output.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1999.3 GB, 1999307276288 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243068 cylinders, total 3904897024 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d3669

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    97658879    48828416   83  Linux
...
/dev/sda4      3804690432  3902345215    48827392   83  Linux
```

It shows the difference of the number of blocks.

So if I want to create two partitions with exactly the same size, what should I do?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: hint: start the partitions on even cylinder breaks and skip a full cylinder in between the partitions.

Comment: That works. I didn't show the intermediate partitions, in fact their MB positions of start and end are too close.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure but you think something like:

```
parted -s --align optimal /dev/sda -- mklabel gpt mkpart primary 4MiB 1 50% mkpart primary 4MiB 50% 100% set 1 boot
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to askubuntu and thank you for your time and answer.  You could improve it by formatting the command (commands?) you propose as code.  As it is written right now, it is unclear if you talk about 1 single command or several commands.  Some description of why you suggest this is also relevant (something like "using `parted` and more specifically parameters `x` or `y`, you can do this or that").

Answer (score 1):

Say your disk is **/dev/sda** and you want to format with filesystem **ext4**:

```
sudo parted /dev/sda

(parted) mklabel gpt
(parted) mkpart primary ext4 0% 50%
(parted) mkpart primary ext4 50% 100%
```

**NB:** note the % also for 0: 0% (this pulls out some magic)

Check with:

```
(parted) print 
(parted) align-check optimal 1 
(parted) align-check optimal 2
```

Also check with fdisk (get out from parted):

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
```